# igraph add to geographic map

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I'm using R for networks. I've used the 'network' package, but now using 'igraph'.

I can plot the igraph using geographic coords.
I can plot a map using 'maptools'(readShapePoly).

How can I plot the igraph on top of the map?

I have tried new=FALSE and add=TRUE but it doesn't work, plotting the igraph object always overwrites.

```
greece <- readShapePoly.("Z:/GeoData/World_data/Basemaps/Greece/GRC_adm1.shp")

df<-data.frame("from" = c.("Athens", "Iraklio", "Thessaloniki", "Patra"), "to"= c("Thessaloniki", "Thessaloniki", "Athens", "Iraklio"))
meta <- data.frame("name"=c("Athens", "Iraklio", "Thessaloniki", "Patra"), 
               "lon"=c(23.72800,25.13356,22.94090,21.73507),  
               "lat"=c(37.98415,35.33349,40.63229,38.24628))


#plot it
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=T, vertices=meta)
lo <- layout.norm(as.matrix(meta[,2:3]))
plot(greece)
plot.igraph(g, layout=lo, add = T)
```

I've seen this solution, but I don't want to use the cario library as I'm using geographic data, not an image as base plot.
[Using geo-coordinates as vertex coordinates in the igraph r-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647537/using-geo-coordinates-as-vertex-coordinates-in-the-igraph-r-package/30671830#30671830)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
library(raster)
library(igraph)
greece <- getData('GADM', country='GRC', level=1)
df<-data.frame("from" = c("Athens", "Iraklio", "Thessaloniki", "Patra"), "to"= c("Thessaloniki", "Thessaloniki", "Athens", "Iraklio"))
meta <- data.frame("name"=c("Athens", "Iraklio", "Thessaloniki", "Patra"), 
               "lon"=c(23.72800,25.13356,22.94090,21.73507),  
               "lat"=c(37.98415,35.33349,40.63229,38.24628))
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=T, vertices=meta)
lo <- as.matrix(meta[,2:3])
plot(greece)
plot(g, layout=lo, add = TRUE, rescale = FALSE)
```

Obviously you don't want to normalize your layout coordinates to a scale from -1 to 1, because your geo plot does not use that scale. So no `layout.norm()`. However, it seems that the latest `igraph` automatically normalizes the coordinates by default under the hood. At first, I didn't find the responsible `rescale` parameter in the documentation and had to use `debug(plot.igraph)` to trace and see it. (Although it's documented in `?igraph.plotting`.) If you set `rescale=FALSE` and `add=TRUE`, then it should work as expected.

[image]

Comment: This seems a tidy solution. However, when I attempt to reproduce this, the map is very tiny. Also it takes very long to plot the country. Can you elaborate on the scaling parameters you used?

Comment: @user2995175 I doubt that both of your problems have to do with "scaling parameters" I used. Your data is probably to detailed - simplify it. However, without a reproducible example it's just guess work...

Comment: Thanks. I did simplify it. Works faster now.