# Define the plotting area of an igraph plot

Tags: r, plot, social-networking, igraph, network-analysis

I'm trying to plot *igraph* objects for which I have set the xy coordinates.

It's been working fine, but when the plot is produced it is stretched in either the x or y so the network looks distorted.

Does anyone know a way that I can define the plotting area (i.e. tell igraph that I want it to plot on a square of set dimensions)? Or any other way of avoiding this problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting the aspect ratio? From `?igraph.plotting`: "asp: A numeric constant, it gives the asp parameter for plot, the aspect ratio. Supply 0 here if you don't want to give an aspect ratio. It is ignored by tkplot and rglplot."

Comment: @lukeA Thanks for your reply. I've just tried supplying it with 0 and it produces the same graph. 1:1 is the same and 0.5:1 is more or less right, but still a bit out. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide some sort of [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem you are having clearly. We have no idea what you are looking at.

Comment: You might also need `rescale=FALSE`, but then you need to set the plotting window properly.

Comment: agreeing with Gabor, for me `rescale=FALSE` always resolved these positioning problems. e.g. see here for exact node coordinates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647537/using-geo-coordinates-as-vertex-coordinates-in-the-igraph-r-package/30671830#30671830

Comment: Thanks to all!  I managed to fix this by using rescale=FALSE and reading the question shared by deeenes.

Comment: @DomBurns please post your comment as answer, and accept it.

Comment: @GaborCsardi `rescale=FALSE` looks like worked for OP, please post as answer.